# My Bitnami Tomcat Stack (on EC2 AWS) is generating DoS attack

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, java, ddos

I have a very small java web app that is deployed on a Bitnami Tomcat Stack on AWS. We are using this app in the company with only 5-10 user base daily, and generating only below 100MB of traffic per day.

Today I got an email from Amazon that my Amazon EC2 server has been making Denial of Service (DoS) attacks. They have also blocked my outbound udp port 53.

I also have a sudden surge of traffic (320 GB of DataTransfer in the last 8 hours), which causes the billing to go double in one day.

This is tragical for me.. I have not been able to find out how and where this attack is running. I have no clue where to begin, or how to find what is causing this.

I am using ssh key-pairs to connect to the server so it is unlikely someone can have hijacked the root account.

Can someone gave me advice on how to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly, your server was breached by a vulnerability in the version of tomcat you are running: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024900/1695906

Comment: thank you. I am using bitnami tomcat stack for quick deploy. But I haven't updated the tomcat for about 6 months, maybe that was it..